# Problemas jquery ui

Tags: css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Estoy haciendo un sistema de `Drag and drop` con jquery ui.

La parte inicial declarando los elementos sortables o droppables funciona perfectamente, el problema lo tengo en que dichos elementos son apilables, creando grupos entre si y posteriormente siendo separables arrastrando el elemento fuera del grupo que se crea al apilarlos.

A partir de este punto las clases css que se aplican se solapan o no se quitan al terminar la acción.

El código Drag and Drop:

```
 $(".taskRecipient").droppable({
            accept: ".taskRecipient",
            /*greedy: true,*/
            containment: "#capaTask",
            scroll:true,
            classes: {
                "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
                "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
            },
            drop: function(event, ui){

                if($(this).parent().hasClass('taskGroup'))
                {
                        var top = 0;
                        var nombre = "";

                        $(this).siblings('.taskRecipient').each(function(){
                            nombre = "";
                            top = $(this).css('top');
                            nombre = $(this).children('.title').text();
                        });

                        var margin = $(this).css('margin-bottom');
                        var height = $(this).css('height');

                        height = parseInt(height) + 30 + "px";

                        $(this).css('height', height);

                        margin = parseInt(margin) + 25 + "px";
                        $(this).css('margin-bottom', margin);

                        top = parseFloat(top) + parseFloat(30) + "px";

                        if( $(".taskGroup .taskRecipient[data-task = " + ui.draggable.data('task') + " ]" ).length )
                        {
                        }else{
                            $(this).parent().append("<div id='" + ui.draggable.data('task') + "' class='taskRecipient ui-widget-content ui-state-default taskGroupElement' data-task='" + ui.draggable.data('task') + "' style='top:" + top +"' >" + ui.draggable.html() + "</div>");
                            ui.draggable.remove();
                            var groupId = $(this).parent().data('groupid');
                            var taskId = ui.draggable.data('task');

                            $.ajax({
                                url: base_url + 'Task/addTaskToTaskGroup',
                                type: "post",
                                data: {
                                    'taskId'    : taskId,
                                    'groupId'   : groupId,
                                    'autor'     : $('#employeeId').val() 
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    menu[1].click();
                                },
                                error: function(){
                                }
                            });

                        }
                }else{

                    var objectTaskId = $(this).data('task');
                    var objectTaskContent = $(this).html();
                    var taskId = ui.draggable.data('task');
                    var taskContent = ui.draggable.html();
                    var aux = $(this);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: base_url + 'Task/createTaskGroup',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {
                            'userId'    : $('#employeeId').val(),
                            'taskIdUno' : aux.data('task'),
                            'taskIdDos' : ui.draggable.data('task'), 
                        }, 
                        success: function(e){
                            var taskGroup = "<div class='taskGroup ui-widget-content ui-state-default' data-groupId='" + e + "'><input type='text' class='taskGroupTitleInput' Placeholder='Nombre de Grupo' /><span class='taskGroupTitle'></span><div class='taskRecipient ui-widget-content ui-state-default' data-task='" + objectTaskId + "'>" + objectTaskContent + "</div><div class='taskRecipient ui-widget-content ui-state-default taskGroupElement' data-task='" + taskId + "'>" + taskContent + "</div></div>";
                            aux.parent().append(taskGroup);
                            aux.remove();
                            ui.draggable.remove();
                            $('.taskGroupTitleInput').focus();

                            $(".taskGroup .taskRecipient").droppable({
                                accept: ".taskRecipient",
                                greedy: true,
                                drop: function(event, ui){
                                    var top = 0;
                                    var nombre = "";

                                    $(this).siblings('.taskRecipient').each(function(){
                                        nombre = "";
                                        top = $(this).css('top');
                                        nombre = $(this).children('.title').text();
                                    });

                                    var margin = $(this).css('margin-bottom');
                                    var height = $(this).css('height');

                                    height = parseInt(height) + 30 + "px";

                                    $(this).css('height', height);

                                    margin = parseInt(margin) + 25 + "px";
                                    $(this).css('margin-bottom', margin);

                                    top = parseFloat(top) + parseFloat(30) + "px";

                                    if( $(".taskGroup .taskRecipient[data-task = " + ui.draggable.data('task') + " ]" ).length )
                                    {
                                    }else{
                                        $(this).parent().append("<div id='" + ui.draggable.data('task') + "' class='taskRecipient ui-widget-content ui-state-default taskGroupElement' data-task='" + ui.draggable.data('task') + "' style='top:" + top +"' >" + ui.draggable.html() + "</div>");
                                        ui.draggable.remove();
                                        var groupId = $(this).parent().data('groupid');
                                        var taskId = ui.draggable.data('task');

                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: base_url + 'Task/addTaskToTaskGroup',
                                            type: "post",
                                            data: {
                                                'taskId'    : taskId,
                                                'groupId'   : groupId,
                                                'autor'     : $('#employeeId').val() 
                                            },
                                            success: function(){
                                                menu[1].click();
                                            },
                                            error: function(){
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                },
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(){
                        }
                    });
                }

           $('.taskGroup .taskRecipient').draggable({
            connectToSortable: '.col-lg-3',
            classes: {
                "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
                "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
            },
            start:function(){
                $(this).addClass('cajaTask');
            },
            stop:function(){
                $(this).css('top', 'auto');
                $(this).removeClass('taskGroupElement');
                $(this).parent().removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                $(this).parent().css('padding-bottom', '-10%')
            }
        });


             $('.col-lg-3').sortable({      
            connectWith: ".col-lg-3",
            update: function(event, ui){

                var ordenElementos = $(this).sortable("toArray").toString();
                var taskParent = $(this).attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + 'Task/changeTaskPosition',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'tasksId' : ordenElementos,
                        'parent' : taskParent,
                    },
                    succes:function(){
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    },
    error: function(e){
    }
```

A día de hoy no tengo claro que se pueda hacer lo que pretendo con jquery ui.

Comment: Hola Korzan. No está claro tu problema. Es con CSS?

Comment: Básicamente si, uno de mis problema (entre otras cosas) es que me mantiene la clase ui-droppable-hover cuando suelto los elementos pertenecientes a un grupo. Al ser un sistema con tanta interacción me es complejo de explicar (seria mas cómodo poder enseñarlo). Otro detalle es que el draggar elementos en ciertas posiciones de la pantalla desaparece de esa posición y aparece en otra sin soltarlo

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces un [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) con un ejemplo funcionando?

Comment: me va a llevar un rato, pero voy a programarlo y lo cuelgo junto a la pregunta

Comment: He añadido enlace para que podáis ver esta parte del proyecto, concretamente es la parte de Tareas. Si necesitáis cualquier cosa decidmelo estoy atento

Comment: Bueno al final tras muchos cabezazos he conseguido que funcione casi perfectamente. solo me falta depurar algunos detalles. Normalmente publico la respuesta cuando la encuentro pero en esta ocasión es demasiado larga como para poder hacerlo decentemente por aquí. Gracias por la atención :)